# DataFrame has no object called str when using headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DF

```
ID   FULL_NAME
1    John Dee
2    Mary Ann
```

I get this DF from a Postgres table using the following method:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
headers = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
return cur.fetchall(), headers
```

Then I tranform the data in a dataframe using this code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data))
df.columns = [header]
```

I want to generate a column in the DF named FIRST_NAME, I'm using this code to do this:

```
df['FIRST_NAME'] = df['FULL_NAME'].str.split().str[0].astype(str,errors='ignore')
df['FIRST_NAME'] = df['FIRST_NAME'].str.strip()
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'. Did you mean: 'std'?
```

If I remove the header part (`df.columns = [header]`) I get another error:

```
KeyError: 'FULL_NAME'
```

When I get this data from SQL Server it generates correctly the `FIRST_NAME` column. When I use Postgres I got this errors. Why is this happening?

Comment: remember df['FULL_NAME'] is a Series -- calling split() on it doesn't make sense; you have to apply it to each element of the Series

Comment: i'd suggest removing all calls to ```str()``` from your code.  stringifying things often has unexpected side effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your dataframe's `FULL_NAME` column, you can create a column of first names using:

```
# break out the first name
first_names = [nm.split()[0] for nm in df['FULL_NAME']]
```

and assign it as a new column in the dataframe:

```
df['FIRST_NAMES'] = first_names
```

Comment: I'll accept your answer as correct since it worked. But I solved this problem in a different way. My SQL Server cursor returns I used `as_dict=True`. In my `psycopg2` I wasn't using this parameter, so I've added `cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor` in my cursor return. Then, `df['FIRST_NAME'] = df['FULL_NAME'].str.split().str[0].astype(str,errors='ignore')` works fine. By the way, thank you so much for the answer, it's good to know that this problem has multiple ways to be solved!